# How do I stop my Magic 8 Ball Program from generating a random number when no question is asked on Python?

Tags: python, random

I have modified my 8-Ball program on Python to perform different operations based on whether a name is entered or not, if a question is not asked or not, etc.

Everything works perfectly except that I can't figure how to turn off the random number generator which keeps spitting out a new correlating answer even when no question has been asked.

Here is my code entered with no question, if you run the program you will see both the message that the user did not enter in their question in addition to the randomly generated answer. Can you help?

```
import random
# who is playing the game
name = 'Chantel'
# ask a yes or no question
question = ''
# answer to question
answer = ''
# random answer generator
random_number = random.randint(1, 12)
# print(random_number) tester

# run a test of the program

# adjusts answer if there is no name entered or prints out an alternate message if no question is 
asked
if name == '':
  print('Question: ' + question)
if question == '':
  print('You forgot to enter in your question for the Magic 8-Ball!')
else:
  print(name + " asks: " + question)
  print('Magic 8-Ball Answer:')


# random answers generated
if random_number == 1:
  print('Yes, definitely')
elif random_number == 2:
  print('It is decidedly so.')
elif random_number == 3:
  print('Without a doubt.')
elif random_number == 4:
  print('Reply hazy, try again.')
elif random_number == 5:
  print('Ask again later.')
elif random_number == 6:
  print('Better not tell you now.')
elif random_number == 7:
  print('My sources say no.')
elif random_number == 8:
  print('Outlook not so good.')
elif random_number == 9:
  print('Very doubtful.')
elif random_number == 10:
  print('I would keep trying.')
elif random_number == 11:
  print('I would not doubt it.')
elif random_number == 12:
  print('100%')
else:
  answer = 'Error'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to indent the answer block so it's inside of the `else`:

```
else:
    print(name + " asks: " + question)
    print('Magic 8-Ball Answer:')

    # ^ Aligned with the above lines now ^
    if random_number == 1:
        print('Yes, definitely')
    elif random_number == 2:
        print('It is decidedly so.')
    elif random_number == 3:
        . . .
```

With how you have your code setup, the `else` block will only run when they enter a question, so that's where you should put code that you want to only run when they've entered a question.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark! That fixed it right up! I understand now that I needed to indent the randomly generated answers to fall under the else condition. Otherwise, it runs as its own operation free of the else that I had created in the event that no question was entered.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to insert the answers to the correct if in this case it is the else:

```
import random
# who is playing the game
name = 'Chantel'
# ask a yes or no question
question = ''
# answer to question
answer = ''
# random answer generator
random_number = random.randint(1, 12)
# print(random_number) tester

# run a test of the program

# adjusts answer if there is no name entered or prints out an alternate message if no question is 
asked
if name == '':
  print('Question: ' + question)
if question == '':
  print('You forgot to enter in your question for the Magic 8-Ball!')
else:
  print(name + " asks: " + question)
  print('Magic 8-Ball Answer:')

  # random answers generated
  if random_number == 1:
    print('Yes, definitely')
  elif random_number == 2:
    print('It is decidedly so.')
  elif random_number == 3:
    print('Without a doubt.')
  elif random_number == 4:
    print('Reply hazy, try again.')
  elif random_number == 5:
    print('Ask again later.')
  elif random_number == 6:
    print('Better not tell you now.')
  elif random_number == 7:
    print('My sources say no.')
  elif random_number == 8:
    print('Outlook not so good.')
  elif random_number == 9:
    print('Very doubtful.')
  elif random_number == 10:
    print('I would keep trying.')
  elif random_number == 11:
    print('I would not doubt it.')
  elif random_number == 12:
    print('100%')
  else:
    answer = 'Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple if statement. Just do all these stuff when:

```
if question != '':
  #Code Here#
else:
  print('Sorry you did not asked any question!!! Try Next time')
```